# Move files from folder 1 to folder 2 if the folder 2 does not contain the file

Tags: python, copy, python-os

I need to write python code to move a file from one folder (Folder 1 )to another (Folder 2) if the folder 2 does not contain the file. I want to know if we should use shutil.copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out

```
if not os.path.exists('destination path'):
    shutil.move("path/to/current/file.foo",
                "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
```